# Add Columns Values with Shell

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I've an input file which looks as below.

```
pmx . pmnosysrelspeechneighbr -m 1 -r

INFO: The ROP files contain  suspected faulty counter values.
They have been discarded but can be kept with pmr/pmx option "k" (pmrk/pmxk) or highlighted with pmx option "s" (pmxs)


Date: 2017-11-04
Object              Counter                  14:45  15:00  15:15  15:30
UtranCell=UE1069XA0 pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      0      1      0      0
UtranCell=UE1069XA1 pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      0      0      0      0
UtranCell=UE1069XA2 pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      0      0      0      0
UtranCell=UE1069XA3 pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      0      0      2      0
UtranCell=UE1069XB0 pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      0      0      0      0
UtranCell=UE1069XB1 pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      0      0      0      3
UtranCell=UE1069XB2 pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      0      0      0      0
UtranCell=UE1069XB3 pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      0      0      0      0
UtranCell=UE1069XC0 pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      0      0      0      0
UtranCell=UE1069XC1 pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      0      0      0      4
UtranCell=UE1069XC2 pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      0      0      0      0
UtranCell=UE1069XC3 pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      0      0      1      0
UtranCell=UE1164XA0 pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      0      3      0      0
UtranCell=UE1164XA1 pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      0      0      0      0
UtranCell=UE1164XA2 pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      1      0      0      0
```

Now I want the output as below which is basically sum of the time column (from `$3` to `$6`) values.

```
Counter                  14:45  15:00  15:15  15:30
pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr      1      4      3      7
```

I've been trying with below command. But it's just giving sum of one column values:

```
pmx . pmnosysrelspeechneighbr -m 1 -r | grep - i ^Object| awk '{sum += $4} END {print $1 , sum}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **sum each of the columns** separately:

```
awk -v g=pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr '$0 ~ g { for(i=3;i<=6;i++) sum[i]+=$i } 
                                  END { printf g; for(i=3;i<=6;i++) printf OFS sum[i] }' file
```

but only for lines (records) containing the group (counter) of interest (`$0~"pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr"`).

Note you (almost) never need to pipe `grep`'s output to `awk`, because `awk` already supports extended regular expressions filtering with `/regex/ { action }`, or `var ~ /regex/ { action }`. One exception would be the need for PCRE  (`grep -P`).

---

As an alternative to `awk` for simple "*command-line [statistical operations](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/html_node/Available-Operations.html#Available-Operations)*" on textual files, you could also use [GNU `datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/).

For example, to sum columns 3 to 6, but group by column 2:

```
grep 'UtranCell' file | datamash -W -g2 sum 3-6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, you will get both header and trailer as sum of individual columns.

```
BEGIN { 
   trail="pmNoSysRelSpeechNeighbr"; 
}
{
    if($1=="Object") print $2 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $5 OFS $6;
    else if($1 ~ /^UtranCell/) {
        w+=$3; x+=$4; y+=$5; z+=$6;
    }
}
END {
    print trail OFS w OFS x OFS y OFS z;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can I use it in a single line?